# Linear programming, unexpected solution with equality constraint

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my implementation, I expect the result to be `[5, 10]`, I don't understand how it gets `[7.5, 7.5]`, `x1` should be half of `x2`.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np

c = [-1, -1]

A_eq = np.array([
    [1, 0.5],
    [1, -0.5],
])

b_eq = [15, 0]

x0_bounds = (0, None)
x1_bounds = (0, None)

res = linprog(
    c,
    A_eq=A_eq.transpose(),
    b_eq=b_eq,
    bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds),
    options={"disp": True})

print res.x
# =>                                                                                                                                                                                 
# Optimization terminated successfully.                                                                                                                                              
#          Current function value: -15.000000                                                                                                                                        
#          Iterations: 2                                                                                                                                                             
# [ 7.5  7.5]
```

Update from the author:

As it was said matrix transposition is not needed here.
The problem was in the matrix itself, in order to get desired result, which is `[5, 10]`, it has to be:

```
A_eq = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [1, -0.5],
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [scipy linprog docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html):

> Minimize: c^T * x
>
> Subject to:
>
> A_ub * x <= b_ub
>
> A_eq * x == b_eq

So, you are now solving the following equations:

```
Minimize -x1 -x2
```

Subject to,*

```
x1 + x2 = 15 (i)
0.5 * x1 - 0.5 * x2 = 0 (ii)
```

Now, (ii) implies x1 = x2 (so your desired solution is infeasable), and then (i) fixes x1 = x2 = 7.5. So, the solution returned by `linprog()` is indeed correct. Since you are expecting a different result, maybe you should look into the way you translated your problem into code, as I think that's where you will find both the issue and the solution.

*) Since you are taking the transpose.

Comment: Thanks, original question was without matrix transposition, did it this way unconsciously probably due to a late evening, basically found out how to achieve desired result, the first row in the matrix has to be `[1, 1]`, thanks once more.

Comment: @RustyRobot it is good to hear that you found out where the problem was. You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
x1 + x2 == 15
0.5 * x1 - 0.5 * x2 == 0

minimize -x1 -x2
```

So obviously you have `x1 == x2` (second constraint), and thus `x1 = x2 = 7.5` (first constraint).

Looking at your question, you probably don't want to transpose `A`:

```
res = linprog(
    c,
    A_eq=A_eq,
    b_eq=b_eq,
    bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds),
    options={"disp": True}
)
```

Why gives you the problem:

```
x1 + 0.5 * x2 == 15
x1 - 0.5 * x2 == 0

minimize -x1 -x2
```

And you get `x1 = 7.5` and `x2 = 15` (the only possible values).